# Python flask request

Tags: python, flask, post

I'm in the middle of developing a Python app and using flask.
I am now writing a POST function that should add a message to a database.
Here is the function I wrote:

```
@app.route('/AddMessage', methods=['POST'])
def AddMessage():
    m=Message(session_id=1, user_id=user.applicatio_id, content='some message', participants=['Ben','Keren','john'])
    db.session.add(m)
    db.session.commit()
    return 'ok'
```

But it sends me such an error message:

```
    Method Not Allowed
The method is not allowed for the requested URL.
```

What's wrong with my POST function?

Comment: To me your decorator declaration seems fine, could you post the "calling" code  (the one that actually makes the POST call) ?

Comment: Are you trying to GET your endpoint as in are you trying to reach to it via a browser?

Comment: Do you mean this one?
http://127.0.0.1:5000/AddMessage
In the meantime, I approached the function that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentionned in the comments,

You are trying to reach your endpoint calling 127.0.0.1:5000/AddMessage in your browser.

Doing this, you are implicitly calling a GET on 127.0.0.1:5000/AddMessage.
My recommendation is trying to call it using curl or Javascript to make a POST call.

In the meantime, for a debug purpose, you could just add "GET" to your accepted methods.